# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined with next-auth and ldapjs

Tags: next.js, next-auth, ldapjs

I am trying to set up LDAP authentication in my application, but I have an error.

When I click on the button, the form becomes empty, and nothing happens.
I try again, and I have the following error :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9pri.png)

My [...nextauth].js :

```
const ldap = require("ldapjs")
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "LDAP",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "DN", type: "text", placeholder: "" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // You might want to pull this call out so we're not making a new LDAP client on every login attemp
        const client = ldap.createClient({
          url: "ldap://192.168.1.143:389",
          tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
        })

        // Essentially promisify the LDAPJS client.bind function
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          client.bind(credentials.username, credentials.password, (error) => {
            if (error) {
              console.error("Failed", error)
              reject()
            } else {
              console.log("Logged in")
              resolve({
                username: credentials.username,
                password: credentials.password,
              })
            }
          })
        })
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      const isSignIn = user ? true : false
      if (isSignIn) {
        token.username = user.username
        token.password = user.password
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      return { ...session, user: { username: token.username } }
    },
  }
})
```

My _app.js

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
import Layout from '@/components/layout/Layout'
import '@/styles/globals.css'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

My index.js

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  const { status } = useSession({
    required: true,
  })

  return (
    <>

    </>
  )
}
```

Can someone help me ?
Thanks.

I followed this documentation : https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/ldap-auth-example

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)